# Using an external text editor to edit VBA code

Tags: notepad++, vba, gvim, sublime-text-2

I have inherited a lot of VBA code to maintain and so far I am using the VBE. Sometimes is quite hard to do some tasks, like advanced text search, so usually I export the module, edit the content with vim and import the modified module to test the code.

This can get a little messy and boring. I know that VBE can be COM automated, so I was thinking if there is a way (like a plugin or a script) to use an external Text Editor (vim, notepad++ or sublime text) to write VBA code and then refresh it automatically in the VBE

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AkelPad has VB scripts enabled, so try to ask at Akelpad site about it. Also PSPad has.

Comment: I made a script to refresh my project and AkelPad worked just fine. Thank you, @Ingo

Comment: How do I turn syntax highlighting on and choose the syntax language in AkelPad?

Comment: @kb_sou Could you share some details about how you refresh the project please?

Answer (score 4):

Recently I found [Text Edit Anywhere](http://www.listary.com/text-editor-anywhere), and using one hotkey I can now get a notepad++ editor window synchronized with the Excel code editor.

The only problem I did not manage to solve so far is that Cyrillic letters fail to pass from notepad++ to Excel: as soon as I save the script once, all they are converted to question marks (although copy-paste from notepad++ preserves the letters). Other than that I'd highly recommend the solution: it allows you to edit text in any program with any editor.

Comment: I can't upvote this workaround enough times.

Comment: Just tried that application because I was tiered (again) of the pretty basic VBE functionality concerning editing text. Combining this application with Sublime Text 3 + VBScript package using `PATH\TO\ST3\subl.exe -nw "%1"` with vba as extension to set correct file text automatically is a pretty decent solution for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) can work with VBscript as well. You'll need this [VBscript Package](https://github.com/SublimeText/VBScript) (github) to access the syntax.

[image]

Comment: Well, that's just for syntax highlighting... Is there anyway to directly edit it from ST without the need to copy/paste in excel's editor again ?

Comment: Export your module as a `.bas` and then edit it and reimport it